# Why does this regex check return true for this string?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex

I need a regex that will determine if a string is a tweet URL. I've got this

```
Regexp.new(/http:|https:\/\/(twitter\.com\/.*\/status\/.*|twitter\.com\/.*\/statuses\/.*|www\.twitter\.com\/.*\/status\/.*|www\.twitter\.com\/.*\/statuses\/.*|mobile\.twitter\.com\/.*\/status\/.*|mobile\.twitter\.com\/.*\/statuses\/.*)/i)
```

Why does it return true for the following?

```
"https://i.stack.imgur.com/QdOS0.jpg".match(Regexp.new(/http:|https:\/\/(twitter\.com\/.*\/status\/.*|twitter\.com\/.*\/statuses\/.*|www\.twitter\.com\/.*\/status\/.*|www\.twitter\.com\/.*\/statuses\/.*|mobile\.twitter\.com\/.*\/status\/.*|mobile\.twitter\.com\/.*\/statuses\/.*)/i))? true : false
    => true
```

Comment: If you use Regexp.new('http://', 'i'), you safe yourself some escaping troubles.

Comment: see [strfriend](http://strfriend.com/vis?re=http%3A|https%3A\%2F\%2F%28twitter\.com\%2F.*\%2Fstatus\%2F.*|twitter\.com\%2F.*\%2Fstatuses\%2F.*|www\.twitter\.com\%2F.*\%2Fstatus\%2F.*|www\.twitter\.com\%2F.*\%2Fstatuses\%2F.*|mobile\.twitter\.com\%2F.*\%2Fstatus\%2F.*|mobile\.twitter\.com\%2F.*\%2Fstatuses\%2F.*%29)

Comment: Answer is already given but I just want to leave this site here, it always helps me out greatly when struggling with regexps: [Rubular](http://bit.ly/e8G1IM)

Comment: @Maran, notice: this site uses 1.8.7.

Comment: @giraff Or use `%r{http://...}`

Answer (score 4):

`http:` will always match a URL starting with `http:`

Try the following:

```
/https?:\/\/(twitter\.com\/.*\/status\/.*|twitter\.com\/.*\/statuses\/.*|www\.twitter\.com\/.*\/status\/.*|www\.twitter\.com\/.*\/statuses\/.*|mobile\.twitter\.com\/.*\/status\/.*|mobile\.twitter\.com\/.*\/statuses\/.*)/i
```

The question mark will make the `s` optional, thus matching `http` or `https`.

Answer (score 2):

Your regex could be abbreviated like :

```
#^https?://(:?www\.|mobile\.)?twitter\.com/.*?/status(:?es)?/.*#i
```

**explanation:**

```
#                       regex delimiter
^                       start of line
https?                  http or https
://                     ://
(:?                     start of non capture group
www\.|mobile\.          www. or mobile.
)?                      end of group
twitter\.com/           twitter.com
.*?                     any number of any char not greedy
/status                 /status
(:?es)?                 non capture group that contains possibly  `es`
/.*                     / followed by any number of any char
$                       end of string
#i                      delimiter and case insensitive
```

Answer (score 2):

No need for regular expressions here (as usual).

```
require 'uri'
uri = URI.parse("http://www.twitter.com/status/12345")
p uri.host.split('.')[-2] == 'twitter' # returns true
```

More docs at: http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/

Comment: +1 for cutting to the chase and sidestepping the regex bullet.

Answer (score 1):

You should group your OR-Clauses, like this:

```
(http:|https:)
```

Additionally, it wouldn't hurt to specify beginning and end of it:

```
^(http:|https:).*$
```

Comment: Or, if you don't need to capture the clause, `(?:http:|https:)`.

Answer (score 0):

The start of your regex specifies an option of just 'http:', which naturally matches the URL you are testing. Depending on how strict you need your check to be, you could just remove the http/https parts from the start of the regex.

Answer (score 0):

While many other answers show you a better regex, the answer is because `/foo|bar/` will match either `foo` or `bar`, and what you wrote was `/http:|.../`, hence all URLs will be matched.

See @giraff's answer for how you could have written the alternation to do what you expect, or @M42's or @Koraktor's answers for a better regexp.

*And as posted in the comments, note that you can write a regex literal as `%r{...}` instead of `/.../`, which is nice when you want to use `/` characters in your regex without escaping them.*

Comment: I like the %r-Syntax, but how would you add the i-modifier to it?